# C++ When should I std::ctype<char>::widen()?

Tags: c++, stl, locale, ostream, ctype

Apparently, writing a single character of type `char` to a stream whose char type is `char` is guaranteed by the standard to not invoke `ctype<char>.widen()` on the associated locale.

On the other hand, according to my reading of the standard (C++17), when writing a string of chars (`const char*`) instead of a single char, `ctype<char>.widen()` must be invoked.

I am struggling to understand how to make sense of this.

On one hand, the fact, that `widen()` is required when writing strings, suggests that there are valid scenarios where `widen()` has an effect. But if that is the case, then how can it be alright to omit the widening operation when writing single characters?

It seems to me that there must be an intended difference in the roles (domains of applicability) of the two operations, output of single char (`char`) and output of string (`const char*`), but I do not see what it is.

To make things more concrete, let us say that I wanted to implement an output operator for a range object, and have the output be on the form `0->2`. My first inkling would be something like this:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Range& range)
{
    // ...
    out << "->"; // Invokes widen()
    // ...
}
```

But, is this how I am supposed to do it? Or would `out << '-' << '>'` (no widening) have been better / more correct?

Curiously, the formulation of the standard suggests to me that the two forms do not always produce the same result. Also, as far as I can tell, the latter form (with separate chars), could be much faster on some platforms.

What is the upshot? What are the rules that should guide me in choosing between the two types of output operations?

For reference, here is an earlier attempt of mine at posing the same question (3 years ago): [C++ What is the role of std::ctype<char>::widen()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44380123/c-what-is-the-role-of-stdctypecharwiden)

Since the old question never got much traction, I'd prefer to mark that one as a duplicate of this one, rather than vice versa.

EDIT: I recognize that a good output operator might not want to use formatted output operations internally, but that is not what I am interested in here. I'm interested in the reasoning behind the difference in behavior of the two types of output operations.

EDIT: Here is one explanation that would make sense to me: `<<` on single char is to be understood as a special case of `<<` on `std::string`, and not as a special case of `<<` on `const char*`. But, is this the right explanation? If so, I believe it means that I should use `<< "->"` above. Not `<< '-' << '>'`.

EDIT: Here is what makes me think that the explanation above (2nd EDIT) is not the right one: In the case of a `wchar_t` stream, both `<<` on `char` and `<<` on `const char*` invokes `widen()`, so from this point of view, they are in the same "family". So, from a consistency point of view, we should expect that when we switch stream type from `wchar_t` to `char`, either both of those operators should still invoke `widen()`, or both should not.

EDIT: Here is another kind of explanation, which I don't think is right, but I'll include it for exposition: For a `char` stream `out`, `out << "->"` has the same effect as `out << '-' << '>'`, because even though the first form is required to invoke `widen()`, `widen()` is required to be a "no op" on a `char` stream in any locale (I don't believe this is the case). So, while there may be a significant difference in performance, the results are always the same. This would suggest that the difference in formulation of required behavior is a kind of unintended, but fairly benign accident. If this is the right explanation, then I should chose `out << '-' << '>'` due to the possibly much better performance.

EDIT: Ok, I found another 3 year old question from myself, where I am coming at it from a slightly different angle: [C++ When are characters widened in output stream operator<<()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377346/c-when-are-characters-widened-in-output-stream-operator?rq=1). The comments from Dietmar Kühl suggests that `widen()` is always a "no op" on a `char` stream, and the whole "issue" is due to imprecise wording in the standard. If so, it would render my second proposed explanation above correct (4th EDIT). Still, It would be nice to get this corroborated by somebody else.